# Open installed apps in iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, launching-application, openurl

Is it possible to open an iPhone app by just knowing app name like follows?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"AppName://"]];
```

Or should i use some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can open it only when the target app has mentioned it in the custom URL scheme. See [Link](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Comment: The developer doesn't need to add a custom URL scheme just to open the app. It's only necessary to do a specific task on launch.